# How to view what is inside the parameter when using MySqlCommand..Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@sampleVariable", sampleVariable))

Tags: mysql, vb.net

For example I have this query

```
    MySQL_Query = "UPDATE `owner_info` " _
    & "SET isArchived = 1 " _
    & "WHERE id=@ownerID"

    Dim MySQL_CMD As New MySqlCommand(MySQL_Query, MysqlConn)

    Try
        MySQL_CMD.Connection.Open()
        MySQL_CMD.CommandText = MySQL_Query
        MySQL_CMD.Parameters.Add(New MySqlParameter("@ownerID", ownerID))
        MySQL_CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        Console.WriteLine("Error: Owner Info Delete")
        Console.WriteLine(myerror)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Close()
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

If I use

```
console.writeline("Query: " & MySQL_Query")
```

It will output

```
UPDATE `owner_info` SET isArchived = 1 WHERE id=@ownerID
```

Is there a way that I can view what's inside the `@ownerID`?

Yeah I can do something like the below code, but it seems hassle?

```
console.writeline("Query: " & MySQL_Query" & "(" & ownerID & ")")
```

Is there any other way to do this? Maybe a more simple way.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters("@ownerID").Value` In that code,  its always going to be the value of `ownerId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of query parameters is that parameter data values are **never** substituted into the sql command text, even by the database server. In this way, any possibility of an injection vulnerability is eliminated. Thus, there is *nothing* built in to provide a populated or annotated command text, lest some naive programmer mistakenly use it to construct vulnerable queries.

However, you could easily build a re-usable method:

```
Function PrintQuery(ByVal cmd As IDbCommand) As String
    Dim result As New StringBuilder(cmd.CommandText)
    result.Append(vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "--Parameter List: ")
    For Each p As DbParameter In cmd.Parameters
        result.AppendFormat("{0}--({1} —— {2})", vbCrLf, p.ParameterName, p.Value)
    Next p
    Return result.ToString()
End Function
```